# Storybook in Create-react-app: typeError: args.flat is not a function

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I have installed storybook in a `create-react app` application thanks to the command `npx -p @storybook/cli sb init`. Then, I added a basic story to the stories folder. When launching storybook, it crashes and says: `typeError: args.flat is not a function`

Here is my story:

```js
import React from "react";
import Hello from "./components/Hello";
import faker from "faker";

const text = faker.internet.email();
export const Default = () => {
  return <Hello text={text} />;
};
```

And the config:

```js
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.js'],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/preset-create-react-app',
    '@storybook/addon-actions',
    '@storybook/addon-links',
  ],
};
```

I tried to replace it with a custom config:

```js
import { configure } from "@storybook/react";

function loadStories() {
  const req = require.context("../src/stories", true, /\.stories\.js$/);
  req.keys().forEach((filename) => req(filename));
}

configure(loadStories, module);
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Upgrade your node version, any version above 12 must work.

If you are using nvm

```
nvm install --lts
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with below command that is supposed to automatically detect underlying framework. Launching storybook fails with `args.flat is not a function` error

`npx -p @storybook/cli sb init`

Use this instead

`npx -p @storybook/cli sb init --type react`

If you already have storybook pre-installed and face this error, overwrite it with -f command

`npx -p @storybook/cli sb init --type react -f`

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same problem today and fixed it by installing `Storybook v. 5.3.19` through [Manual setup](https://storybook.js.org/docs/guides/guide-react/#manual-setup)
. Looks like there are some compatibility problems between `create-react-app` and Storybook 6.+ beta-versions.

Comment: nvm use 14.4.0 fixed the situation as well. Thanks! However, I can't access any stories yet for an unknown reason, I'll try downgrading the version.